# Copy the latest files from the directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell, directory, scp

I have the following files in a `data` directory: `myfile1.txt` `myfile2.jnx` `myfile3.sur`.

I use the below command to copy the contents of the above directory to another location:

```
scp data/* remotehost.example.com:/data/
```

However, I find an issue when the contents of the directory are dynamically changed after issuing the command. Like the file `myfile3.sur` changed to `myfile3.sur1` by another application that works on this directory in the background while the first file is still copying.

I know shell would translate `*` to the all the file names in that directory when I trigger my command. Is there a way to tell linux to include the changed/updated files too?

Answer (score 1):

While this is not the direct answer, I'd suggest using `rsync` for this: https://medium.com/@sethgoldin/a-gentle-introduction-to-rsync-a-free-powerful-tool-for-media-ingest-86761ca29c34

Comment: It won't address the issue described in the question

Answer (score 0):

In order to ensure that the wanted file with name as is and content as is will be transfer make a script with the following logic:

```
mkdir data/temp.$$
cp data/* data/temp.$$
scp data/temp.$$/* remotehost.example.com:/data/ 
rm data/temp.$$
```

By copy-moving the files to a temp dir in the same server will ensoure that the later tansfer will get the file.

**Note** that if the files are constantly changed by background processes try to make dependancies with those processes.